# Adding values to an ArrayList<byte[]> and can only retrieve the final value added

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a University project and have come to a problem I can't figure out.

I add a number of byte[] (byte arrays to an ArrayList and when I read back the values, all values are a duplicate of the last value added.

I need this ArrayList to be accessible to the rest of my programme.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Puzzles {

    static ArrayList<byte[]> puzzleList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    public static void getPuzzles() throws Exception
    {
        //Create 4096 128 zero bits followed by unique 16 bit random puzzle number.
        ArrayList<byte[]> puzzles = Puzzles.createPuzzles();
        //Array list to store the final completed puzzles.
        ArrayList<byte[]> complete = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

        byte[] puzzleKey;
        DES a = new DES();

        for(byte[] puzzle: puzzles)
        {
            byte[] fullPuzzle = new byte[26];
            puzzleKey = a.generateRandomKey();
            System.arraycopy(puzzle, 0, fullPuzzle, 0, puzzle.length);
            System.arraycopy(puzzleKey, 0, fullPuzzle, fullPuzzle.length-puzzleKey.length, puzzleKey.length);
            //System.out.println("puzzle="+ CryptoLib.getHexStringRepresentation(puzzle));
            byte[] secretByte = createKey();
            SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretByte, 0, secretByte.length, "DES");
            byte[] puzzleBytes = a.encrypt(fullPuzzle, secret);
//          unencryptedPuzzleList.add(fullPuzzle);
            complete.add(puzzleBytes);
        }
        FileInOut writer = new FileInOut();
        writer.writeToBin(complete);
    }   

    public static ArrayList<byte[]> createPuzzles()
    {       
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=1; i<4097; i++)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        byte[] messageNumber = new byte[18];
        byte[] uniqueNumber = new byte[2];
        for (int n=0; n<4096; n++)
        {           
            uniqueNumber = CryptoLib.smallIntToByteArray(list.get(n));
            System.arraycopy(uniqueNumber, 0, messageNumber, messageNumber.length-uniqueNumber.length, uniqueNumber.length);
            System.out.println("messageno"+CryptoLib.getHexStringRepresentation(messageNumber));
            puzzleList.add(messageNumber);----> **here is the problem.**
        }
        System.out.println("check="+ CryptoLib.getHexStringRepresentation(puzzleList.get(44)));
        return puzzleList;
    }

    public static byte[] createKey()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int key = r.nextInt(65536);
        byte[] bkey = new byte[8];
        byte[] messageKey = CryptoLib.smallIntToByteArray(key);
        System.arraycopy(messageKey, 0, bkey, 0, messageKey.length);
        return bkey;    
    }

}
```

I've marked the ArrayList puzzleList that's what is causing the issues.

I think its to do with the Arraylist being declared as static. 
 Java is not a strong point of mine and I'm probably making a silly mistake.

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: You create the array once before the loop, that is why you are adding the same array at every iteration. There is only one array. `byte[] messageNumber = new byte[18];` is the problem. Move it into your loop.

Comment: Thank you.  I've looked and looked but didn't see that.